# .net System.Text.RegularExpressions nesting regexps in regexp

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to ask any skilled .net developer, if there is a possibility to define regular expression (using the .net `RegularExpressions` namespace cpabilities), which would include references to another regexp(s). I would like to describe grammar rules, each rule as a single regexp. The final regexp would be the grammar's start symbol.

Of course I can perform the expansion to single line regular expression, but the readability would suffer. I also would not like to try each option included in start symbol programatically (like `foreach(regexp r in line.regexps) {check if r.matches(input)}`).

For example having following ini-like file grammar in regexp-like form (does not follow microsoft regexp rules, just general ones):

```
sp           = \s*
allowed_char = [a-zA-Z0-9_]
key          = <allowed_char>+
value        = <allowed_char>((<allowed_char>|[ ])*<allowed_char>)?
comment      = (;|(//)|#)(.*)

empty_line   = ^<sp>$
line_comment = ^<sp><comment>$
section      = ^<sp>\[<sp><value><sp>\]<sp>(<comment>)?$
item         = ^<sp><key><sp>=<sp><value><sp>(<comment>)?$

line         = <empty_line>|<line_comment>|<section>|<item>
```

I would like to:

- Check if a sentence is part of the language (true/false) - seems trivial: matches the `<line>` start symbol.
- Access the terminal-like symbol values (e.g. `<section>`, `<key>`, `<value>`, `...`) - I suppose this could be achieved via named matching groups (or whatever exactly is it called - still nedd to read some details at msdn).
- I do not expect you to write the code, just if you could give me some hints, whether it is possible (and how) or not, because I have not found this info yet. All examples are for single regexp matching.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with when I was doing my own regex based mathematical expression parser:

```
private static class Regexes {
    // omitted...
    private static readonly string
        strFunctionNames = "sin|ln|cos|tg|tan|abs",
        strReal = @"([\+-]?\d+([,\.]\d+)?(E[\+-]?\d+)?)|[\+-]Infinit(y|o)",
        strFunction = string.Format( @"(?<function>{0})(?<argument>{1})", 
            strFuncitonNames, strReal );

    // omitted...
    public static readonly Regex
        FunzioniLowerCase = new Regex( strFunctionNames ),
        RealNumber = new Regex( strReal ),
        Function = new Regex( strFunction );
}
```

This has the obvious disadvantage that there's some sort of repetition in the code, but you could use reflection to compile (and perhaps even create) those regexes in a static constructor.

Comment: I see, so you do the expansion, but use substitution on string level... If there is no possibility how to reference the regexps in another regexp, this might be one of solutions. Thank you.

Comment: As there is no other possibility to include sub-expressions in Regex classes, this is the only solution.